# Different behavior in DependencyProperty's RegisterAttached() and Register()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I find this question during code reading. After search MSDN, it has same issue too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501.aspx
For DependencyProperty.Register method, it has code example like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentReadingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...);
public double CurrentReading
{
  get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentReadingProperty); }
  set { SetValue(CurrentReadingProperty, value); }
}
```

For RegisterAttached method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597496.aspx , it has code example like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBubbleSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(....);
public static void SetIsBubbleSource(UIElement element, Boolean value)
{
    element.SetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty, value);
}
public static Boolean GetIsBubbleSource(UIElement element)
{
    return (Boolean)element.GetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty);
}
```

My question is, RegisterAttached doesn't use property format and use 2 static functions. Why?

Comment: When you search the web for "attached behavior" or check the WPF documentation for classes with the suffix Service. You will see that this has some additional advantage. The class, declaring the attached property doesn't need to be derived from DepedencyObject, in fact its all static method, so your class can be completely static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached.aspx) and the associated static methods are for registering [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) like `Canvas.Left`, which are defined in one class, but can be set on instances of any other class (derived from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)). You can for example set `Canvas.Left` on a Button in code like this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(button, 100);
```

You need a static set method since you cannot add a `Left` property to class Button.